# What is the standard for testing in Java?

Tags: java, testing, junit

What apps  would you use? Are there auto testing suites like autotest for ruby? What do you use and why? To be honest, I don't even know how to write tests, when, or why. I'd like to learn though, I know that it will make me a better developer.

Our team uses Netbeans, not eclipse, although I'm going to still google eclipse responses to see if they are implemented as a Netbeans solution as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 most popular frameworks for unit tests: JUnit and TestNG. Both are annotation based. To create test you have to create class and mark each method that performs test using annotation `@Test`.

JUnit is older and have more extensions (DBUnit, Cactus etc). TestNG has much more annotations. Very important feature of TestNG is ability to create test groups using annotations.

Yet another group of tools you will probably need is mocking tools (EasyMock, EasyMock etc.)

Comment: What are "testgroups"? If it's what I assume it is, JUnit can also bundle different Junit tests together.

Comment: @Voo, You are right. But JUnit requires writing TestSuite to group tests. TestNG allows grouping by simple annotation. Moreover you can add test to several group and add different test from the same test case to different groups.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I could see that being useful sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of testing frameworks that are popular.  JUnit is pretty good and comes by default with Eclipse.  It provides an API for defining tests and doing assertions, as well as a Testrunner to execute the tests. EasyMock and Mockito work well with JUnit to provide mocking functionality so you can test components in isolation.

For continuous integration, there is Jenkins, which is free.

There are others as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would use junit and possibly a mocking library like jmock.

Most of the automatic "tests" which can be done use the compiler or a code analysis tool like FindBugs.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget TestNG.  It's the "next generation" beyond JUnit.  It handles threaded tests better.

SOAP UI is the right tool for testing SOAP web services.

JMeter or Grinder for load testing.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has already been said (JUnit, EasyMock, ...) you may also have a look at [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/): it may be a good tool for full integration and acceptance tests!

Answer (score 1):

As JUnit and Mockito was already mentioned, You can look into Infinitest or JUnit Max for autotesting.

http://infinitest.github.com/

http://junitmax.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something that implements continuous testing I can recommend two free products:

For a developer during work in Eclipse/IntelliJ IDE:

http://infinitest.github.com/

Infinitest is an Eclipse/IntelliJ plugin that runs your test continuously in the background while you are developing your code.

For a team:

http://hudson-ci.org/ 
or
http://jenkins-ci.org/

are great continuous integration servers that can do builds and run tests continuously.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for but we work in netbeans.

Comment: See if there's a way for NetBeans to integrate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Been writing junits for over 7 years now and I highly recommend [spock](http://www.spockframework.org) for all your testing needs: unit and integration testing, mocking, end-to-end testing, data driven testing etc